# stocke methode Js into Json

Tags: javascript, json

I have an API server who stock this Json :

```
const jsonElm = { "Initialize1": "Initialize1": { get:  function () { console.log('bonjour Man'); }},"Initialize2": "Other Initialiszer","Other": "Other Function"};
```

for Initialize1 i trying this, but it's it's juste seen like a texte Area.. 
i can't execute the function

`enter code here`"Initialize1": "function () { console.log('bonjour Man'); }",

```
const JsonStr = JSON.stringify(jsonElm);
const JsonObj= JSON.parse(JsonStr);
```

the Initialize1 objetJson is not possible like this.. To finish my idea, the rest of the script is :

```
var obj = { }

Object.defineProperties(o, {
    JsonObj.Initialize1,
    JsonObj.Initialize2,
    JsonObj.Other
});

obj.Initialize1(); // say just Hello Man in console
obj.Initialize2();// for exemple this initializer  add an EventListener for HTML div.
```

is it possible or Json Can't stocke methode

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) Among other things, it doesn't have functions. If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. What you have is an object, not JSON.

Comment: What you've shown isn't valid syntax (you get a syntax error as of the second colon). Please update the question to show your actual code for the object.

Comment: Why are you converting `jsonElm` to a string (JSON), then parsing that string? What are you trying to do by doing that?

Comment: Thanks you T.J, OK . so an API cant delivring any javascript ?

Comment: APIs can deliver JavaScript. It's usually not best practice, but they can. But JavaScript != JSON.

Comment: I know this script can't work this is an example / image of the result I'm looking for

Comment: My problem is: create an web interface, which just embeds an indexe.html.
it retrieves the necessary from the API server (to feed the HTML).
but for the JS, I want it to be a minimum protected ...

Comment: ok so i understand today what is my error...

i search the solution on the Wrong Way !

All i need is it the API server who execute. THNAKS YOU T.J